# ImportError: cannot import name write_dot

Tags: python

```
# Load required modules
import textwrap, os
from time import strftime
from networkx import write_dot
from networkx import connected_components
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "multi_dendrix_pipeline.py", line 36, in <module>
    import multi_dendrix as Multi   File "/home/shruti/ToolKit/multi-dendrix-master/multi_dendrix/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import output   File "/home/shruti/ToolKit/multi-dendrix-master/multi_dendrix/output/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from output_functions import *   File "/home/shruti/ToolKit/multi-dendrix-master/multi_dendrix/output/output_functions.py", line 6, in <module>
    from networkx import write_dot ImportError: cannot import name write_dot
```

System info:
Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
OS Type 64bit
Python : Python 2.7.6

Other info
installed networkx and can locate the files under usr/local/lib/pyton2.7/dist-packages

Comment: You should update your question with a proper error description, details about what you are doing and - of cause - a question.

Comment: check if `usr/local/lib/pyton2.7/dist-packages` is in `sys.path`. `python -c 'import sys. print("usr/local/lib/pyton2.7/dist-packages/networkx" in sys.path)'`. If not, set `PYTHONPATH`. `PYTHONPATH=usr/local/lib/pyton2.7/dist-packages/networkx:$PYTHONPATH python script.py`

Answer (score 3):

You need to change this line:

```
from networkx import write_dot
```

to

```
from networkx.drawing.nx_agraph import write_dot
```